# Visual Studio 2013 Crash When Rebuilding SalesInvoice SSRS Report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am facing VS crash problem after copying SSRS report design.

I need to modify SalesInvoice SSRS report. Our normal practice is to make a copy of the design we are going to modify before starting modification.

Before i copy the design (design_1), i do rebuild to SalesInvoice, the rebuild can be success with two warmings.

Successful Compile Msg:

[image: Successful Compile Msg]

After duplicated a design by copying and pasting it, i tried to rebuild the copied design, i got following error message.

Compile Error Msg:

[image: Compile Error Msg]

I remove the copied design (design_1) and try to copy other design (design_2). design_2 can be rebuilt successfully.

I tried to duplicate other designs, only some of them has rebuild error.

I believe that it should be some error in those designs.

is there any way i can easily locate what and where the problem is in those report designs?

My environment is AX 2012 R3 CU11 (6.3.4000.127) with VS 2013 version update 5 (12.0.40629.00) and SQL 2012 64-bit (11.0.6567.0).

We upgraded AX from R2 to R3 this year and the report has no such issue before.

Comment: I'm not sure it has to do with which design was copied because the error message complains about the connection to the AOS. Are you sure you did both times the same things? Could you also [edit] into your question which designs (I guess they were two of the standard designs) you copied so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually, we have 19 designs in the report. i am guessing either the design has problem or report size has limitation.

Comment: I restored SalesInvoice report to sys layer version, it's already 21.4 MB and have 8 designs inside. I tried to make a copy of reportTH design and rebuild the report several times (i can success rebuild it in first few times), the same error can be reproduced.

Comment: Thx for your help. FH-Inway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reducing obsolete report design, the problem can be fixed. Too many designs will cause report size too big and it will lead VS becomes unstable when compiling.

Comment: How did you find out that the size causes the compilation to fail?

Comment: I removed all designs from sys layer and its size reduced to 10 sth MB. By doing this, the report can be built smoothly. Also, I can duplicate several designs from usr layer and modify it without error.

Comment: Per the findings, I also found other persons met same issue, you can have a look by refer these links: 1) https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/126693 2)http://techemall.blogspot.hk/2016/01/unable-to-connect-to-aos-specified-in.html 3)https://dynamicsuser.net/.../ssrs-compile-error-in-visual-studio